# Mechanize get a file instead of a page object

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

i try to scrap a web page. I use Nokogiri/ Mechanize. so if i make

```
page = agent.get(url)
page.class
 => Mechanize::File
```

, sometimes i get a page object sometimes a file object. but what i need is, everytime a page object. i tried to add a pluggable_parser for plain/text but this don't work for me.

have anyone an idea how i can fix it, or how i can find out the content-type from a file object or know, how i can cast a file to an page object?

Thanks Michael

Comment: With the same URL or with different ones?

Comment: with the same url, i think its a dirty html code or something like that. i didn't have a problem with other sides to get a page object. i try out a workarount and download the file to make a page object from file with the uri.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the page you're requesting is unavailable and the server returns a plaintext error page.

See the docs on [Mechanize::File](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/File.html).

The content type is in `page.response['content-type']`.

It's definitely possible to change the content type of the response and then create a [Mechanize::Page](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html) from the data without having to download it again - but I don't think that would give you anything useful.

Check the response code as well, it's in `page.code`.

Comment: => {"server"=>"nginx", "date"=>"Thu, 09 Jun 2016 16:27:07 GMT", "content-type"=>"text/html ; charset=UTF-8", "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked", "connection"=>"keep-alive", "expires"=>"Wed, 08 Jun 2016 16:27:07 GMT", "x-powered-by"=>"PleskLin"} 


but still Mechanize::File. dont know why.